# Running an Ant target under certain conditions

Tags: ant

I have the following Ant targets in my project.xml:

```
<target name="to.run.under.conditions"> 
</target> 

<target name="deploy1"> 
    <antcall target="deploy2"/>
</target>

<target name="deploy2">
    <antcall target="to.run.under.conditions"/>
</target>

<target name="another.target">
    <antcall target="deploy1"/>
</target>
```

My intent is to be able to exclude the target `to.run.under.conditions` when running `another.target`. I am not very familiar with ANT and I am struggling to understand how to approach the issue. I have tried to employ `unless="${target.running}"` in  and set the property as true in the condition task inside the `target name ="target.running"`

Can you help with this?

Thank you for your help,

I.

----EDIT UPDATED SOLUTION----

This is my current attempt (I am using ANT 1.8.2):

```
<target name="to.run.under.conditions" if="${target.running}"> 
</target>

<target name="another.target">
<property name="target.running" value="false"/> 
</target>
```

If I am not mistaken, since the property is set to false inside `another.target`, then `to.run.under.conditions` should not be run (I might be wrong, though). Does it make sense? Any comment is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with this solution that seems to be work as expected:

```
<target name="deploy2">
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${target.running}" arg2="true" />
        <then>
            <echo message="the target will not run" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <echo message="the target will run" />
                <antcall target="to.run.under.conditions"/>
        </else>
    </if>   
  </target>

    <target name="to.run.under.conditions"> 
    </target>

    <target name="another.target">
    <property name="target.running" value="true"/>  
    </target>
```

Hope this helps,

I.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<target name="build-module-A" if="module-A-present"/>
<target name="build-own-fake-module-A" unless="module-A-present"/>
```

In the first example, if the module-A-present property is set (to any value, e.g. false), the target will be run. In the second example, if the module-A-present property is set (again, to any value), the target will not be run.

Please see [Any Targets](https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) for more information.

Comment: @MJG, thanks for your reply. Can you please put this in the context of my issue? This is something taken directly from https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html and i am not sure how this would apply to my example.